# QML/Qt gradient charts

Tags: qt, charts, qml, gradient

I want to create a charts in QML/Qt (solutions for both "platforms" will suffice). Here is an example of what I want: [image: Text]

I draw charts like this:

```
ChartView {
    title: "Температура"
    antialiasing: true
    legend.visible: false
    height: parent.height
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.left: parent.left

    SplineSeries {
         color: "#5fafff"
         XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0 }
         XYPoint { x: 0.5; y: 1.1 }
         XYPoint { x: 1.0; y: 2.9 }
         XYPoint { x: 1.5; y: 2.1 }
         XYPoint { x: 2.0; y: 4.9 }
         XYPoint { x: 2.5; y: 3.4 }
         XYPoint { x: 3.0; y: 4.1 }
    }
}
```

But how to add a gradient here?

Comment: `SplineSeries` is just a line, I guess that you have to use `AreaSeries` instead. Not sure but you can try to use `AreaSeries.brushFilename` i.e. assign to the property path to a image file that contains some gradient. I guess that using `Gradient` or something like this is unavailable here. You can use some external libraries, maybe Canvas to paint the graph by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want just gradient in your series, not like area gradient you can use Glow and Linear Gradient together which you will anchor with your glow. Also you can use that link for create your visual gradient easly. [https://cssgradient.io/](http://cssgradient.io)
so here is the simple example of usage:

> ```
>    Glow {
>             id:glow
>             anchors.fill: yourchartid
>             radius: 18
>             samples: 168
>             color: "purple"
>             source: yourchartid 
>
>     }
> ```

```
LinearGradient {
            id:gradient
            // 200 is length of gamut
            start:Qt.point(200,0)
            end:Qt.point(0,0)
            gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop {
                            position: 1;
                            color: "#312c36";
                    }

                    GradientStop {
                            position: 0.5;
                            color: "#5f4a69";
                    }


                    GradientStop {
                            position: 0.2;
                            color: "#a600ff";
                    }
           }
           anchors.fill: glow
           source: glow
    }
```